# Untagging socket failed /w Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I have a `volley` library `JsonObjectRequest` that causes warnings/errors.

```
03-17 10:13:27.634    1401-1418/com.myapp.app I/qtaguid﹕ Untagging socket 47 failed errno=-2
03-17 10:13:27.634    1401-1418/com.myapp.app W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger﹕ untagSocket(47) failed with errno -2
```

It starts to receive the request, but somewhere in the middle it is interrupted and I have absoluteley no clue why. If I copy the URL in the browser everything works fine. The formatted JSON is about 2500 lines.

I'm grateful for every little hint.

Comment: That's weird... I saw on Internet that it could be related to poor WiFi connection... But they were not sure :/

Comment: I found out the logcat output size was too small set and so the output was cut off. Anyway... thanks for your thoughts, @Andy!

Comment: Nice that you found a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

"qtaguid" will tag or untag every socket in order to stats traffic usage, I think, when the socket fd is closed unexpectedly,untag on this socket fd will cause error, that is ok, just ignore this error.